# pandas `read_sql_query` - read `double` datatype in MySQL database to `Decimal`

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, decimal, read-sql

I'm trying to use `read_sql_query()` to read a query from  MySQL database, one of the field in the database, its type is `double(24, 8)`, I want to use `dtype=` parameter to have full control of the datatypes and read it to `decimal`, but seems like pandas can't recognize `decimal` type so I had to read it to `Float64`

In the database, the values for this field look like this:

```
Value
100.96000000
77.17000000
1.00000000
0.12340000
```

Then I'm trying to read it from Python code:

```
from decimal import *

dtypes = {
        'id': 'Int64',
        'date': 'datetime64',
        'value': 'Float64'
    }

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, mysql_engine, dtype=dtypes)
```

but after reading the data from the code above, it looks like this:

```
Value
100.96
77.17
1.0
0.1234
```

How can I read this column to `decimal` and keep all the digits? Thanks.

Comment: A number can be _represented_ in many ways.  Show us the code that is generating `0.12340000`, the code that is reading that, and the cod that is displaying `0.1234`.

Comment: Hi I don't have the code that's generating `0.12340000` (that's the bit I'm asking), that's what the data look like in the database. The code is generating `0.1234` is the code on the top of my question.

Comment: Please show us the code that _reads the data and displays_ `100.96`.

Answer (score 0):

What "the data looks like in the database" is tricky.  This is because the act of printing it out feeds the bits through a formatting algorithm.  In this case it removes trailing zeros.  To see what is "in the database", one needs to get a hex dump of the file and then decipher it; this is *non-trivial*.

I *believe* that `DECIMAL` numbers hold all the digits specified, packed 2 digits per byte.  No, I don't know how they are packed (0..99 versus 2 hex digits; what to do if the number of digits is odd; where is the sign?)

I *believe* that `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` exactly conform to IEEE-764 encoding format.  No, I don't know how the bytes are stored (big-endian vs little-endian).  I suspect Python's `Float64` is IEEE `DOUBLE`.

For `DECIMAL(10,6)`, I would expect to see "1.234" to be stored as `+`, `0001`, and `234000`, but never displayed with leading zeros and optionally displayed with trailing zeros -- depending on the output formatting package.

For `DOUBLE`, I would expect to find hex `3ff3be76c8b43958` after adjusting for endianism, and I would not be surprised to see the output be `1.23399999999999999e+0`.  (Yes, I actually got that, given a suitable formatting in PHP, which I am using.)  I would hope to see `1.234` since that is *presumably* the intent of the number.

Do not use `DOUBLE(m,n)`.  The `(m,n)` leads to extra rounding and it is deprecated syntax.  Float and Double are not intended for exact number of decimal places; use `DECIMAL` for such.

For `FLOAT`:  1.234 becomes hex `3f9df3b6` and displays something like `1.2339999675751` assuming the output method works in `DOUBLE` and is asked to show lots of decimal places.

Bottom line:  The output method *you* are using is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks, I don't have control on the database side, so I can't change the way the data is storing in the DB, the field is `Decimal` type in the database, my original question is how I can specify the type to keep it as `Decimal` after reading the data using `read_sql_query()` if this makes sense.

Comment: @Cecilia - `DECIMAL(m,n)` keeps the trailing zeros.  The _display_ mechanism is removing them !!